# Difference in SQL between join... on ... join ... on .... VS. ... join ... join ... on ... AND

Tags: sql, hiveql

I recently optimized a HiveQL request (by > 300x) that looked something like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM a
        LEFT JOIN b
        LEFT JOIN c
        LEFT JOIN d
        ON a.col1 = b.col2 AND
        b.col3 = c.col4 AND 
        c.col5 = d.col6
```

To this:

```
    SELECT * FROM 
        a LEFT JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col2
        LEFT JOIN c ON b.col3 = c.col4
        LEFT JOIN d ON c.col5 = d.col6
```

Is the latter code always faster in SQL or does it have something to with the Hadoop Map/Reduce operations in Hive ?

Comment: Have you tried using EXPLAIN to see how each query is executed? Or is that not a thing in Hive?

Comment: yes, it exists, I will try this

Comment: I'm actually quite scared that the first code executes.  You have 2 joins without any join criteria, and then a 3rd join that contains the criteria for all 3 joins.  The fact that the compiler can do something with it is moderately impressive... in a scary way.

Comment: @Bruce I believe that the syntax should be equivalent

Comment: Unless there's something special about HiveSQL, I would expect the original syntax to effectively cross join A and B and C, and then only when it joins to D will it start filtering things out.  If that's what it's doing, then it would make sense that you moving the join criteria to the correct spot would improve performance by a massive amount.